# What is the difference between "Equal" and "SequenceEqual"?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

When should i use "Equals" and when "SequenceEqual"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SequenceEqual` is used to compare collections, because if you use `Equals` to compare two collections of something, it will also take into account the actual type of the collection, while `SequenceEqual` will compare the contents only.